# Rearrange nodes using xslt by using date as key

Tags: xslt-1.0

Is it possible to rearrange the xml segments by moving the last instance of a segment to the last part of the message. Please see samples below:

Original structure:

```
<Header>
<Field>20170201</Field>
</Header>
<Header>
<Field>20170203</Field>
</Header>
<Line>
<Field>20170202</Field>
</Line>
```

Desired output:

```
<Header>
<Field>20170201</Field>
</Header>
<Line>
<Field>20170202</Field>
</Line>
<Header>
<Field>20170203</Field>
</Header>
```

In the sample above, the 2nd instance (or last instance of Header) was moved after the Line node.

Comment: Google `xslt sort`. -- P.S. What you have are numbers, not dates (although they do represent dates). XSLT 1.0 does not know how to sort by date, but sorting by the numbers that you have will have the same effect.

Comment: ok sir michael, i guess the date format that i'm using is much more complex. YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.xxxxxZ . You were right about not using the date. Can I instead just move the last instance after the last segment?

Comment: That format too is sortable, using `"text"` as the `data-type`.

Comment: hi michael, can i use sort even if the field used is part of different segments? like in the sample, Header and Line..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Michael for the solution!
It was indeed simple. thanks again!

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="MainNode">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates>
         <xsl:sort data-type="text" select="Field"/>
         </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```